# React 17 Use Conditional Switch in Function Return

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do condition rendering in the latest version of React 17, which does not have Render, only Return.

How Can I get this switch statement working? Currently its not returning anything from my switch statement.

```
const Search = (props) => {

  let test = 'foo';
  return (
    <div>
      {function() {
        switch(test) {
         case 'foo':
          return 'foo12345';
         case 'bar':
          return 'bar67890';
         default:
          return 'aaaa';
         }
        }
      }      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Using functions over class based method. Will have to use 8-10 condition switch statement in future,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're just declaring a function, but never executing it. Simplest tweak would be:

```
return (
    <div>
        {
            (function () {
                switch (test) {
                    case 'foo':
                        return 'foo';
                    default:
                        return 'bar';
                }
            })()
        }
    </div>
)
```

But a much better approach would be:

```
return (
    <div>
        {
            test === 'foo' ? 'foo' : 'bar'
        }
    </div>
)
```

If you have lots of possibilities, I'd recommend an object or Map, it's much more concise and less error-prone than `switch`.

```
const obj = {
  foo: 'foo12345',
  bar: 'bar67890',
  // etc
};
```

```
return (
    <div>
        {
            obj[test] || 'aaaa'
        }
    </div>
)
```

Comment: The first part of my answer shows how to use `switch` with that - you just need to execute the function. But using a plain object and using object property lookup would probably be a lot easier to manage.